# Core plot Memory consumption issue with arc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, core-plot

I am building a graph related app with ARC enabled in which there are two different views on the graph:
-One is the small view which i have to change on the click of a button(using reload data).
-The second view is the large one on which the graph changes when buttons like i.e. "1 day","3 days","5 days" clicked.

The problem i am facing is, after 15-20 minutes of continuous use the application get crashed with log...."CAAnimation failed to allocate bytes".
When i analyzed on Profile i get to know that when small graph loads the live bytes jumps by 2-3 mb and when large graph loads live bytes jumps by 4 to 5 mb and live bytes then never comes down.
I nilled all graph objects on on leaving the view but even then the memory is not released.

on switching to the next graph i am calling this method:

```
-(void)removePlot
{
    for(CPTPlot* plot in [graph allPlots])
    {
        plot.dataSource = nil;
        plot.delegate = nil;
        [plot deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(0, plot.cachedDataCount)];
        [graph removePlot:plot];
    }
}
```

and on leaving the view i am calling this method:

```
-(void)removeGraph
{
    [axisSet removeFromSuperlayer]; 
    axisSet=nil;
    [self removePlot];
    generationPlot=nil;
    [graph removePlotSpace:plotSpace];
    plotSpace=nil;
    [graph removeFromSuperlayer];
    graph=nil;
    [hostView removeFromSuperview];
    hostView=nil;
    headerList=nil;
    graphDetailList=nil;
    graphList=nil;
    dataList=nil;
    plotsArray=nil;
}
```

Many people  have faced this problem earlier but no answer gonna work for me yet.
If any one have any idea regarding this...please help.

Comment: I am facing same problem and amazingly still no answer in 10 months :)

Comment: Do you have a very simple example project which I could look at that demonstrates this behaviour? Or did you find a solution already?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this, it may be helpful.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/introduction/introduction.html

Also, consider looking into the @autoreleasepool mechanism that ARC provides to help limit the maximum memory footprint.

Also, make sure the methods you list above are being called. Sometimes we write cleanup routines but they don't get called! :-)

Also, You list the code as:

axisSet=nil
generationPlot=nil
...etc...

what type is axisSet? what type is generationPlot? A global variable? If they aren't NSObjects (and sometimes even if they are) setting them to nil may not be the proper way to deallocate them.

Consider making some of them a @property and give them proper qualifiers (ie: strong, etc.) then some of your memory usage may be a little clearer. If you have a number of static or globals that may be causing some confusion.

Hope this helps.